# What is the most proper way to add radio button in JSP page?

Tags: jsp, radio-button

I need to add radio button to a JSP page. e.g. Media type. It can be either text, audio, video, image.

Database will have int column for media type. like 1 for text, 2 for audio so on.

Generally this is what we do in JSP to add radio buttons,

```
Text : <input type ="radio" name = "mediaType" value = "1"/>
Audio: <input type ="radio" name = "mediaType" value = "2"/>
```

I don't want to hard code these values in JSP.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that hard coding is the proper standardized way of adding components into the form unless you've got a **UI** which would allow drag-and-drop function to pull the components into the Form.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: so If i need to do some operation based on media type in code. I would have to do if mediaType == 1.